# SQL Server(SQLEXPRESS) Service

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-express

I am trying to start SQL Server(SQLEXPRESS) service from Sql Server Configuration Manager. I got following error:

> The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion. Consult the event log or other application error logs for details.

I checked out error logs. Here is the error:

> initerrlog: Could not open error log file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG'. Operating system error = 3

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the account SQL Server is operating under has write permissions to `'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Log`, after you've verified that the directory actually exists.

First go to Services (Control Panel/Administrative Tools/Services) and check which account SQL Server is running under. Probably `NT Service\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS`

Then go to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL' and right click on the "Log" folder and click properties. Then go to the Security Page. If `MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS` is listed, ensure that it has "Full Control" if it doesn't, click the "Edit" button and give it full control. If it's not listed, click "Edit" and then on the "Permissions for Log" dialog click add and add `MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS`.

Comment: I just noticed that there is no such folder as log under C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL

Comment: Well, that would be a problem.

Comment: For the noob like me, when you add the `MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS` user permission, make sure you typed the full name `NT SERVICE\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS` instead of just `MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS`