# ASP.NET giving SQL Server errors. Possibly due to no log's configured on SQL Server Express

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-express

When I run my ASP.NET application I get this error in my browser:

> The application could not connect to the database, please check the connection string in the web.config file and SQL server availability.

> Original error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)

I checked Event Viewer and found this error:

> initerrlog: Could not open error log file ''. Operating system error = 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).

I have SQL Server Express 2019 installed on my laptop so I checked SQL Server Configuration Manager and found the SQL Server process wasn't running so I tried to start it. It failed with this error:

[image]

Right now I'm assuming it's all part of the same issue.

I checked the start up parameters expecting to see something like `-eC:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG` but there was no parameters and when I tried to add the the `Add` button greyed out.

I'm also unable to connect through SSMS:

> TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> ---
>
> Cannot connect to DESKTOP-GK2MRBG.
>
> ---
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)
>
> For help, click: [http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?>ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=2&LinkId=20476](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?%3EProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=2&LinkId=20476)
>
> ---
>
> The system cannot find the file specified
>
> ---
>
> BUTTONS:
>
> OK
>
> ---

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Are you able to connect to the database server using SQL Server Management Studio? That would be the place to start.

Comment: I'm also unable to connect through SSMS. Error added to question.

Comment: So this is maybe stating the obvious, but... something is wrong with your local SQL Server Express install. Without being there, it's hard to say what it is. I would start with this google search and try every suggestion you find: https://www.google.com/search?q=can+connect+to+sql+server+express+on+localhost&rlz=1C1GCEU_enUS834US834&oq=can%27t+connect+to+sql+server+express+on+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j33i22i29i30l7.13400j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Perhaps this [previous StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18001395/390122) will provide some clues?